# MVC 3 dynamic authorization of multiple roles and users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I recently starded developing for MVC 3 but have experience in both C# and ASP.NET since earlier. So i'll start with what i'm trying to accomplish. I've developed a small site for hosting articles. I've implemented SQLServer based membership managament to the site. Now i want to create a credentials system that restricts and allows the right users to create, delete and update articles. There is one simple solution to this and that is to do it like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult UpdateArticle(ArticleModel model, int articleid)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Now this is really simple. I simply say that only members that are in the role "Admin" are allowed to update an article. But that's just to static. So i created a credentials table in my database that in the end tells me that "Article 5 can be edited by roles 1,2,3 & 4 and by users A, b & C". So far so good. But how would i implement that with the Authorize solution?

I would like to do something like this:

```
[Authorize(getAuthorizedusers("update",this.articleid))]
```

where getAuthorizedusers returns which users and roles are authorized to update the article with the articleid that was passed to it.

So I have (at least) two problems here:
-Getting the Authorize method to accept multiple users and roles.
-Passing the supplied articleid, that was sent to the UpdateArticle method, to the getAuthorizedusers method.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create your own custom attribute that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the `OnAuthorize` method to do what you need.

This should get you started:

```
public class ArticleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public enum ArticleAction
    { 
        Read,
        Create,
        Update,
        Delete
    }

    public ArticleAction Action { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        //do custom authorizization using Action and getting ArticleID 
        //from filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString or
        //filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form
    }
}
```

The usage would look like this:

```
[ArticleAuthorize(Action=ArticleAuthorizeAttribute.ArticleAction.Update)]
```

Edit: After looking into this a bit more, it looks like you can't pass this.articleID in to the attribute. However, you do have access to the parameters from `filterContext.HttpContext.Request` through the `QueryString` property or the `Form` property, depending on how you are passing the values. I have updated the code sample appropriately.

A more complete example can be found [here](http://kbochevski.blogspot.com/2009/11/mvc-custom-authorization.html)

To check for authorization using user role and user list you would do something like this:

```
        var allowedUsers = new List<string>();
        //populate allowedUsers from DB

        If (User.IsInRole("Update") || allowedUsers.Contains(User.Identity.Name))
        {
            //authorized
        }
```

Alternatively, you can do both checks against the DB directly in a single method to keep from making two calls.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I am gonna try to implement this, and come back with the results!

Comment: Hi again! Now i've tried and succeeded partialy. When authorizing with users and roles, it only authorizes the specified users which have the specified roles. I want it to be specified users, or users that have the specified roles. Is that possible to fix somehow?

Comment: @Anton, You will need to query the DB directly for the explicit access. Since you will have to go to the DB directly for part of it, you may want to write a method that takes the username, the role, and the articleID and returns whether or not they have access. `UserCanPerformAction(User.Identity.Name, "Update", 23)`

Comment: I don't think you understood what my problem is, probably because i described it poorly =).
In the OnAuthorizatoin-method, if i write:
    ´Users = "Anton"´
The user "Anton" would be the only one with permissions to do something. If i only write:
    'Roles="Admin"'
Only users in the group "Admin" can do something.
but if i write:
    'Users="Anton
     Roles="Admin"'
The user "Anton" would only be authorized if he has the "Admin" role. But i want the user Anton to be authorized and everyone with the role Admin to Authorized.

Comment: @Anton, I thought that's what you meant :) I've updated my answer to include a brief snippet for checking a user list or role membership for authorization. You would need to write the DB code specific to your situation (ADO.net, Entity Framework, Linq to SQL, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a much easier way to accomplish the same thing:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult UpdateArticle(ArticleModel model, int articleid)
{
    // if current user is an article editor
    return View();
    // else
    return View("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working as I wanted when I overrode the AuthorizeCore method and authorizes the way I want to.

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ((_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```