# Multiple authorisation requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am quite new to MVC and have not even really got the hang of `[Authorize]` yet. Basically, I have a website that for one area, requires them to give their e-mail address, name and company before getting access. No password, no Register etc. Then there will be an `Admin` area where a user will be required to sign in using their email address and password.

My question is, how would I implement a dual authorisation situation?

Also forgot to mention that when in `Admin` area, they can upload material to the sites they are admin to, i.e. more than the one they are currently on. I have a database that holds which sites they are admin for. The URL would be like /Admin/Site/ but once they have logged into admin, how do I make sure they can't go /Admin/Site2 where `Site2` is one they are not admin for.

Comment: You would need to use Roles. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404254/mvc-3-dynamic-authorization-of-multiple-roles-and-users][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404254/mvc-3-dynamic-authorization-of-multiple-roles-and-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the person can be anonymous and download the file as long as she/he provided details before. In that case, ignore the Authorization attribute and write your own.  Here is a quick example. It relies on a cookie to be set.

```
public class CheckEmailAddressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        // if the cookie isn't set the a user never provided their details
        if (request.Cookies["mycookiename"] == null)
        {
            // Set it to the correct result, to redirect the user to provide their email address
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "GetEmailAddress" };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("mycookiename", "true"));
        }
        else
        {
            // Don't do anything, the user already provided their email address
        }

    }
}
```

And specify it like this on the controller that does the download.

```
public class DownloadController : Controller
{
    [CheckEmailAddress]
    public ActionResult Download(string name)
    {
        // Implement download
    }    
}
```

The only thing left is to set the cookie when the email address is set. I assume you know how to do that. You may also want to make sure you have some "returnUrl" parameter so you can redirect the user to the download page once they provided their email address.

**EDIT**

As per OP, we do not want to set the cookie except if the person enters their details, so here is the updated class.

```
public class CheckEmailAddressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        // if the cookie isn't set the a user never provided their details
        if (request.Cookies["mycookiename"] == null)
        {
            // Set it to the correct result, to redirect the user to provide their email address
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "GetEmailAddress" };
            // filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("mycookiename", "true"));
        }
        else
        {
            // Don't do anything, the user already provided their email address
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So, for example, I would have [CheckEmailAddress] on everything inside the press area except the page that asks for their details?

Comment: Also, with this example, all they have to do is go on the page and it sets the cookie. They can be redirected to the page and then simply navigate backwards and then they have the cookie.

Comment: See my update. The cookie should not be set in the attribute.

Comment: So, where is the cookie now set?

Comment: It really depends where you add it.  You can add it to the GlobalFilters, controllers or actions. I have not used areas much, and therefore don't know if you can register an action filter for all controllers in an "area".

Comment: As per my last comment in my original answer, you need to set it in the action that accepts and validated the persons information. I am assuming you know how to do that.

Comment: You assumed wrong :( I created an attribute upon the action that validates and adds the cookie on OnExecuted but this feels dirty