# windows authentication to get a list of users in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

my application uses windows authorisation, but I manually specify the users that have access like this:

```
[Authorize(Users = "domain\\userone, domain\\usertwo, domain\\userthree")]
```

I was wondering whether I could put a loop in there to loop through a list of users that were return from a database call, so for example a quick mock up that would get a list of users' NT accounts from the database:

```
List<string> users = new List<String>();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Default.ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT NT_ACCOUNT FROM USERS";

SQLDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    users.Add(reader.GetValue(reader.FieldCount));
}
```

and a mock up from what I think it would look like for the authorisation:

```
foreach(String nt_account in users)
{
[Authorize(Users = nt_account)]
}
```

or perhaps it could be sone easier with a linq query I'm not sure, the above code is just a guess though.

Comment: why not using just [Authorize] if you want to allow all the users?

Comment: @Sunny Because the list of users is already a table but not everyone on that list is should be allowed access and it would be nice to have some functionality in the portal that allowed or disallowed that access.

Comment: okay, you need to modify the AuthorizeCore method then, see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/a/6426328/1057667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the AuhorizeCore method:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //_usersSplit = ListOfAuthorizedNames
        if ((_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426328/1057667

Comment: giving this a go, it should be the solution