# MVC5 ASP Identity dynamic Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity, authorize-attribute

I have a MVC5 project with backend to configure which role can access which menu. The normal way to implement role based authorization is something like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult UpdateProduct(ProductModel model)
{
     //do something
     return View(model);
}
```

Because I need the roles to be dynamic, I was thinking of something like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles=GetRoles("UpdateProduct"))]
public ActionResult UpdateProduct(ProductModel model)
{
     //do something
     return View(model);
}
```

And obviously it doesn't work because Attributes are static metadata.

I looked around and found this [MVC 3 dynamic authorization of multiple roles and users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404254/mvc-3-dynamic-authorization-of-multiple-roles-and-users) but is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Note: I'm trying to avoid calling `User.IsInRole` in every method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of a code attribute in C# is that it is static - hence why you cannot have a method, `GetRoles()`.

You proposed wanting an attribute such as:

`[Authorize(Roles=GetRoles("UpdateProduct"))]`

This would mean you would have to implement `GetRoles()` in your code so use a custom attribute that is derived from `Authorize`.

```
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string roleSelector)
        {

            Roles = GetRoles(roleSelector);
        }

        private string GetRoles(string roleSelector)
        {
            // Do something to get the dynamic list of roles instead of returning a hardcoded string
            return "Somerole";
        }
}
```

So now you can do:

`[CustomAuthorize("updateProduct")]`